# How to add latest arrivals to my magento homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, products-management

I have already searched everywhere for the answer but found loads of outdated/incomplete and non working answers so thought I would ask here myself.

I simply want to add my newest products onto my homepage so that when you click on a product it takes you to its page where you can buy it.

What would be the best and most simple way to go about this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cms->Pages, enter in your cms home page. Now add

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" column_count="2" products_count="5" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

in `Content` tab and save.

Now, when you will mark a product as "New"(From product details you will set `Set Product as New from Date` and `Set Product as New to Date`) it will appear on homepage in `catalog/product/new.phtml` template.

Comment: I just noticed that on CMS>content you can add a new products widget, that worked but it says 'new products' and I have no idea how to change the title text

Comment: When I put anything in {{ }} in my content box it just displays as text

Comment: You can change or translate the "'new products" text, in one of your csv translation under locale folder.  For example, you can enter in locale/en_US folder and open the Mage_Core.csv. In this file you can change the text like that: 'new products','Your desired text'

Comment: if my answer helped you, please mark it as answered